# SSO SP-Initiated OpenAM

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

I am in the current process of doing a SP Initiated SSO.

- The IDP is PingOne
- The SP (us) is openAM

I always have been doing IDP Initiated SSO.

So we have the IDP Initiated SSO setup and everything is working perfectly.
We have now to make it SP Initiated.

I understand the theory behind it but I have no clue on how to implement it !

So far I was thinking that the URL I need to give them is something like that maybe ??? :

https://sso/saml2/jsp/spSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=/{idpRealm}/sp&idpEntityID={idpEntityId}

But when I hit that I get nothing, just a blank page ?

Some help would definitely be welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be more like:

`https://sp.example.com:8080/openam/spssoinit?metaAlias=/{spRealm}/{spMetaAlias}&idpEntityID={idpEntityID}`

`/spssoinit` is actually just a shortcut to `/saml2/jsp/spSSOInit.jsp`, so you should be able to use either of those. The main point here really is that the metaAlias is always the hosted entity's. If you don't know the exact metaAlias value, you should be able to look it up under the (hosted) entity's configuration in the admin console under the Services tab.

Comment: Ok, yes the URL was wrong, I get to see the redirection to the IDP, but now the SAMLRequest is been passed as a GET parameter, whereas I would like it to be as a POST. I looked in the configuration and I do not see where I should force it, and I added it to the URL : [https://sso.com/sp/saml2/jsp/spSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=/xxx/sp&idpEntityID=xxx&binding=HTTP-POST](https://sso.com/sp/saml2/jsp/spSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=/xxx/sp&idpEntityID=xxx&binding=HTTP-POST)

Comment: "binding" is used for response binding, for request binding you should use the "reqBinding" request parameter with the spssoinit JSP.

Answer (score 0):

It should be link this for SP-initialed SSO

`https://youropenam.com:8443/OpenAM-13.0.0/saml2/jsp/spSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=/YOUR_SP_ALIAS/sp&NameIDFormat=transient&idpEntityID=your_IdP_encoded&binding=HTTP-POST&RelayState=Your_SP_endpoint`